# How to configure HSTS in Wildfly the proper way?

Tags: configuration, https, hsts

I want to set the HSTS header on Wildfly. I haven't found any specific method to do this, so my first approach would be setting it manually via an [undertow filter](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/configuring-undertow-filters-on-wildfly):

```
<filters>
 <response-header name="headers" header-name="Strict-Transport-Security" header-value="max-age=31536000"/>
</filters>
```

Is this the proper way to go or is there a better way to enable HSTS on Wildfly?

Comment: Your approach seems to be the right one. See https://developer.jboss.org/message/845749